# Why does the OMP task run slower than OMP for?

Tags: c, openmp

I am new to the OPENMP and want to use it to solve the wave equation, the serial code is here:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>

#define GRID_SZ 3000
#define ARR_SZ GRID_SZ * GRID_SZ
#define PEAK_SZ 31

double *process_withoutomp() {
    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    int i, j;
    double dt = 0.04, C = 16, K = 0.1, h = 6;
    double *data, *olddata, *newdata, *tmp;
    double x[PEAK_SZ][PEAK_SZ], linspace[PEAK_SZ], delta = 2.0/(PEAK_SZ-1.0);
    data = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*ARR_SZ);
    olddata = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*ARR_SZ);
    newdata = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*ARR_SZ);

    for(i = 0; i < ARR_SZ; i++){
            data[i] = 1.0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < PEAK_SZ; i++){
            linspace[i] = -1.0 + delta * i;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < PEAK_SZ; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < PEAK_SZ; j++){
                    x[i][j] = linspace[i];
            }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < PEAK_SZ; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < PEAK_SZ; j++){
                    data[(i+20)*GRID_SZ+j+20] += h * exp( -5 * (pow(x[i][j], 2 ) + pow(x[j][i], 2 )));
            }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < ARR_SZ; i++){
            olddata[i] = data[i];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            sequential_update_withoutomp( data, olddata, newdata, C, K, dt);
            tmp = olddata;
            olddata = data;
            data = newdata;
            newdata = tmp;
    }
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("without omp spend: %f\n",end-start);

    return data;}void sequential_update_withoutomp(double *data, double *olddata, double *newdata, double C, double K, double dt ){
    int i, j, add_i, sub_i, add_j, sub_j;
    double pot;
    for( i = 0; i < GRID_SZ; i++){
            for( j = 0; j < GRID_SZ; j++){
                    add_i = i+1 >= GRID_SZ ? i : i+1;
                    add_j = j+1 >= GRID_SZ ? j : j+1;
                    sub_i = i-1 < 0 ? 0 : i-1;
                    sub_j = j-1 < 0 ? 0 : j-1;
                    pot = data[add_i*GRID_SZ+j]+
                                data[sub_i*GRID_SZ+j]+
                                data[add_j+i*GRID_SZ]+
                                data[sub_j+i*GRID_SZ]-
                                4*data[i*GRID_SZ+j];
                    newdata[i * GRID_SZ + j] = 
                            ( pow(C * dt, 2) * pot * 2 + 4 * data[i * GRID_SZ + j] - olddata[i * GRID_SZ + j] *(2 - K * dt) ) / (2 + K * dt);
            }
    }}
```

and here is the version using for:

```
double *process_withomp() {
    double start = omp_get_wtime();

    int i, j;
    double dt = 0.04, C = 16, K = 0.1, h = 6;
    double *data, *olddata, *newdata, *tmp;
    double x[PEAK_SZ][PEAK_SZ], linspace[PEAK_SZ], delta = 2.0/(PEAK_SZ-1.0);
    data = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*ARR_SZ);
    olddata = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*ARR_SZ);
    newdata = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*ARR_SZ);

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i) schedule(auto)
    for(i = 0; i < ARR_SZ; i++){
            data[i] = 1.0;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) schedule(auto)
    for(i = 0; i < PEAK_SZ; i++){
        linspace[i] = -1.0 + delta * i;
        for(j = 0; j < PEAK_SZ; j++) {
            x[i][j] = linspace[i];
        }
    }

    #pragma omp barrier

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) schedule(auto)
    for(i = 0; i < PEAK_SZ; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < PEAK_SZ; j++){
            data[(i+20)*GRID_SZ+j+20] += h * exp( -5 * (pow(x[i][j], 2 ) + pow(x[j][i], 2 )));
        }
    }

    #pragma omp barrier

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i) schedule(auto)
    for(i = 0; i < ARR_SZ; i++){
        olddata[i] = data[i];
    }

    #pragma omp barrier

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        sequential_update_withomp( data, olddata, newdata, C, K, dt);
        tmp = olddata;
        olddata = data;
        data = newdata;
        newdata = tmp;
    }


    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("with omp spend: %f\n",end-start);
    return data;}void sequential_update_withomp(double *data, double *olddata, double *newdata, double C, double K, double dt ) {
    int i, j;
    double pot;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,pot) schedule(auto)
    for( i = 0; i < GRID_SZ; i++) {
        for( j = 0; j < GRID_SZ; j++) {
            pot = data[(i+1 >= GRID_SZ ? i : i+1)*GRID_SZ+j]+
                data[(i-1 < 0 ? 0 : i-1)*GRID_SZ+j]+
                data[(j+1 >= GRID_SZ ? j : j+1)+i*GRID_SZ]+
                data[(j-1 < 0 ? 0 : j-1)+i*GRID_SZ]
                -4*data[i*GRID_SZ+j];
            newdata[i * GRID_SZ + j] = 
                        (pow(C * dt, 2) * pot * 2 + 4 * data[i * GRID_SZ + j] - olddata[i * GRID_SZ + j] 
                        * (2 - K * dt)) 
                        / (2 + K * dt);
        }
    }}
```

this version runs well but when I try to use task to replace it, the result is right, but the time spend more:

```
double *process_withomp1() {
    double start = omp_get_wtime();

    int i, j;
    double dt = 0.04, C = 16, K = 0.1, h = 6;
    double *data, *olddata, *newdata, *tmp;
    double x[PEAK_SZ][PEAK_SZ], linspace[PEAK_SZ], delta = 2.0/(PEAK_SZ-1.0);
    data = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*ARR_SZ);
    olddata = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*ARR_SZ);
    newdata = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*ARR_SZ);

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i) schedule(auto)
    for(i = 0; i < ARR_SZ; i++){
            data[i] = 1.0;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) schedule(auto)
    for(i = 0; i < PEAK_SZ; i++){
        linspace[i] = -1.0 + delta * i;
        for(j = 0; j < PEAK_SZ; j++) {
            x[i][j] = linspace[i];
        }
    }

    #pragma omp barrier

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) schedule(auto)
    for(i = 0; i < PEAK_SZ; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < PEAK_SZ; j++){
            data[(i+20)*GRID_SZ+j+20] += h * exp( -5 * (pow(x[i][j], 2 ) + pow(x[j][i], 2 )));
        }
    }

    #pragma omp barrier

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i) schedule(auto)
    for(i = 0; i < ARR_SZ; i++){
        olddata[i] = data[i];
    }

    #pragma omp barrier

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        sequential_update_withomp1( data, olddata, newdata, C, K, dt);
        tmp = olddata;
        olddata = data;
        data = newdata;
        newdata = tmp;
    }


    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("with omp spend: %f\n",end-start);
    return data;}
void sequential_update_withomp1(double *data, double *olddata, double *newdata, double C, double K, double dt ) {
    int i, j;
    double pot;
    #pragma omp parallel private(i,j,pot)
    for( i = 0; i < GRID_SZ; i++) {
        for( j = 0; j < GRID_SZ; j++) {
            #pragma omp task
            {
            pot = data[(i+1 >= GRID_SZ ? i : i+1)*GRID_SZ+j]+
                    data[(i-1 < 0 ? 0 : i-1)*GRID_SZ+j]+
                    data[(j+1 >= GRID_SZ ? j : j+1)+i*GRID_SZ]+
                    data[(j-1 < 0 ? 0 : j-1)+i*GRID_SZ]
                    -4*data[i*GRID_SZ+j];
            newdata[i * GRID_SZ + j] = 
                            (pow(C * dt, 2) * pot * 2 + 4 * data[i * GRID_SZ + j] - olddata[i * GRID_SZ + j] 
                            * (2 - K * dt)) 
                            / (2 + K * dt);
            }
        }
    }}
```

In my mac, the serial version takes around 7.7s, the for version takes 3.7s, but the task using 53s.

Anyone know what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to consider here:

- a) thread **granularity**, i.e. the amount of work per thread
- b) the way of **task creation**

In your code, a) is too small, and b) is broken.

**a)**
In your `task` example, **one iteration of the inner loop** is a task, while in the `parallel for` example, **n iterations of the outer loop** are parallelised, i.e. each thread processes a chunk of iterations of the outer loop. With `schedule(static, 1)`, one outer iteration would be the work-size per thread. Keep in mind, all the parallelism adds overhead, for synchronising stuff, book-keeping, etc.. That added cost, must be compensated for by the increased execution speed of the parallel execution. Finding the right amount of work is crucial, you want as many as necessary to keep everything busy and maybe some more to give the scheduler some room to compensate load-imbalances between tasks/chunks, but as few as possible to keep the overheads small.

**b)**
Running the loop in your parallel region, means that every thread is running the whole loop nest and creates all the tasks multiple times. That's like running the serial program multiple times in parallel.

```
void sequential_update_withomp1(double *data, double *olddata, double *newdata, double C, double K, double dt ) {
// ....
#pragma omp parallel private(i,j,pot)
{
    // split loop among threads of parallel region
    // i.e. create tasks in parallel
    #pragma omp for
    for( i = 0; i < GRID_SZ; i++) {
        // coarse grained tasks (as in parallel for version)
        #pragma omp task
        {
            // each inner for loop is one task
            for( j = 0; j < GRID_SZ; j++) {
                // ...
            }
        } // task
    } // parallel for
} // parallel region
```

This gives me (2 cores x 2 Hyperthreads):

```
serial:        4.839213
parallel for:  2.529813
task:          2.817615
```

**Note:** There is no point here in actually using tasks here, as they only add overhead on top of the parallel for loop.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have fixed my code here:https://github.com/langker/Wave-Equation-2D/blob/master/unit_test.c

Comment: But in my newest version code, the task version is still slower a little than for...In my MAC(2.7 GHz, Intel, Core i5) while GRID_SZ=3000, the task-version is 0.3s slower than for version.